# Vary Field Label by Record Type or Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, formula-field, fields

I currently have a requirement that for a field we have on an object, the label shown to the user is different depending on the page layout or record type.

I can't find any way to change a field label on a per-layout basis, the only idea I had was to have 2 different fields with the different labels, then only place the correct field on the relevant page layout. I could then create a formula field for reporting that would be calculated from whichever of the fields was non-empty.

Does anyone know of a better way to have different labels for the same field?

Comment: Are VF pages an option for you?

Comment: Visualforce pages are an option, but I'd rather not have to go that route because we'd need to re-create all the different layouts for record types. There is also the additional maintenance overhead for any future changes to the layout if they are Visualforce pages.